# Change part of an attribute after cloning with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a table with different inputs. Using a button, I want to clone the last row of the table, and add it to the table. Furthermore, I want to replace the "index" in the name with the variable of the index.

How can I replace the string `"index"` with the variable `index`?

In this example I just show one input, because it is sufficient to get a clue.

```
<table class='taskTable'>
 <tr>
   <td>
    <input name='data[index][description]'></input>
    <input name='data[index][text]'></input>
    <input name='data[index][date]'></input>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<button type='button' class='addTask'>Add Row</button>

<script>  
var index = 1;

$(".addTask").on('click', function(){
    index = index+1;
    var lastTr = $('.taskTable').find('tr:last').clone();
    //replace now the string index of the name with the variable
    $('.taskTable').append(lastTr);
});
</script>
```

Here is a link to the jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/tg53c96m/

Comment: `lastTr.attr("name", "new_name_here")` - what am I missing from the question?  Edit: spotted it, will edit question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the name with `.attr("name", value)`:

```
var newName = `data[${index}][description]`;
lastTr.find("input").attr("name", newName);
```

Or if you want to search/replace:

```
lastTr.find("input").attr("name", 
  (i, oldName) => oldName.replace(/\[.*\]\[/, `[${index}][`));
```

```js
var index = 1;

$(".addTask").on('click', function() {
  index = index + 1;
  var lastTr = $('.taskTable').find('tr:last').clone();
  lastTr.find("input").attr("name", 
      (i, oldName) => oldName.replace(/\[.*\]\[.*\]$/, `[${index}][description]`));
  console.log("New name: ", lastTr.find("input").attr("name"));
  $('.taskTable').append(lastTr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='taskTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name='data[index][description]'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button class='addTask'>Add Row</button>
```

Comment: Essentially the same: you can shorten the code (slightly) by using a different `.attr` overload : https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: Not sure if he want to search/replace or just set

Comment: I just meant, instead of -  get attr, change val, set attr - you can do:  `.setAttr("name", function(i, val) { return val.replace("index", index); })`  (which is essentially what you had so I've not added as a separate answer)

Comment: Allright. We get close. I edited a bit the example (added 2 inputs). In real I have between 5 and 20 Inputs. So I only really want to set the reset the index. The last part (so description, text, date) should keep like they are.

Comment: Ok. Finally, I used your function and edited it a bit to ```lastTr.find("input").attr("name", 
  (i, oldName) => oldName.replace('index', ${index}]));```

Comment: See that this won't work for the second time on, unless you clone the first row (change to `tr:first`), or use the updated regex i put on the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Just saw the edited HTML so here's the added function to handle multiple inputs with different names:

```
    lastTr.find('input').each(function() {
      let nameText = $(this).attr('name');
      let newName = nameText.split('index').join(rows);
      $(this).attr('name', newName);
    });
```

In order to change the pattern of each name without having to remember which one is which is to handle only the portion of the names that actually changes:

```
      let newName = nameText.split('index').join(rows);
```

`nameText` is the current input name which is s String value of either:

```
      'data[index][description]',
      'data[index][text]',
      /* OR */
      'data[index][date]'
```

When `.split()` into an Array of Strings, it removes the text: `"index"`:

```
      nameText.split('index')
      // Returns ['data[', '][`description or text or date`]']
```

Finally `.join()` will convert the Array of Strings into a String with the variable index number between them:

```
      .join(index)
      // Returns `'data['+index+'][`description or text or date`]'`
```

---

1. Add the following statement as the first line of the function:

   ```
   let rows = $('.taskTable tr').length;
   ```

   This will be the number of rows already in the table.
2. Add this after the row has been cloned but before it is appended:

   ```
   lastTr.find('input').attr('name', 'data' + rows);
   ```

   This finds the input nested within the new row and assign it `name="data'+rows`. I'm not sure what's with the `[description]` part of the name.  Is it dynamic or literal like the `[index]` part. It sounds like something isn't quite right about those names...

**Note:** The rest of the name can be whatever, I just feel wrong to have a name looking like that. The contacted string will look like the following with the original text:

```
lastTr.find('input').attr('name', 'data[' + rows + '][description]');
```

Also, I added another function that will change all row input with the new naming pattern.

#### Demo

```js
/* 
This will change all row input names from 
'data[index][description]' 
'data[index][text]'
'data[index][date]'
to
'data['+index+'][description]' 
'data['+index+'][text]'
'data['+index+'][date]'

index = 0,...N
*/
$('.addTask tr').each(function(index) {
  $(this).find('input').each(function() {
    let nameText = $(this).attr('name');
    let newName = nameText.split('index').join(index);
    $(this).attr('name', newName);
  });
});

$(".addTask").on('click', function(index) {
  let rows = $('.taskTable tr').length;
  const lastTr = $('.taskTable').find('tr:last').clone();
  lastTr.find('input').each(function() {
    let nameText = $(this).attr('name');
    let newName = nameText.split('index').join(rows);
    $(this).attr('name', newName);
  });
  $('.taskTable').append(lastTr);
});
```

```html
<table class='taskTable'>
   <tr><td>
    <input name='data[index][description]'>
    <input name='data[index][text]'>
    <input name='data[index][date]'>
   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>
    <input name='data[index][description]'>
    <input name='data[index][text]'>
    <input name='data[index][date]'>
   </td></tr>
</table>

<button class='addTask' type='button'>Add Row</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```